# How to find average from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, average

Example:

```
$a[] = '56';
$a[] = '66';
$a[] = '';
$a[] = '58';
$a[] = '85';
$a[] = '';
$a[] = '';
$a[] = '76';
$a[] = '';
$a[] = '57';
```

Actually how to find average value from this array excluding empty. please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: You should not define integers as strings. Instead of `$a[] = '56';` it should be `$a[] = 56;`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

first you need to remove empty values, otherwise average will be not accurate.

so

```
$a = array_filter($a);
$average = array_sum($a)/count($a);
echo $average;
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/QfrOP6)**

More concise and recommended way

```
$a = array_filter($a);
if(count($a)) {
    echo $average = array_sum($a)/count($a);
}
```

**[See here](https://ideone.com/x1E5GJ)**

Comment: Keep in mind that you should first check to ensure count() is positive, otherwise you'll get a divide by zero error

Comment: array_filter would remove zeros also, skewing the average.

Comment: @MiloLaMar: yes, for that please check Don't Panic's answer below.

Comment: You should make `count` check AFTER you've filtered out empty values

Comment: The double use of the `count()` an add some needless overhead from calling `count()` multiple times. You can either do `$count = count($a);` or just do `if($a)`. Both are good enough solutions. I would use `if($a)` which saves on calling `count()` on empty arrays, but is harder to understand for those starting to learn the language.

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer works for the example values, but in general simply using `array_filter($a)` is probably not a good idea, because it will filter out any actual zero values as well as zero length strings.

Even `'0'` evaluates to false, so you should use a filter that explicitly excludes zero length strings.

```
$a = array_filter($a, function($x) { return $x !== ''; });
$average = array_sum($a) / count($a);
```

Comment: With PHP 7.4+, you can do `array_filter($a, fn($x)=>$x !== '');`, using the syntax for [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.arrow-functions).

Answer (score 7):

```
echo array_sum($a) / count(array_filter($a));
```

Comment: you need to do count(array_filter($a)) in order to not include the empty values.

Answer (score 1):

As a late look, item controls should be done with numeric check. Otherwise something like this `$array = [1.2, 0.33, [123]]` will corrupt the calculation:

```
// Get numerics only.
$array = array_filter($array, fn($v) => is_numeric($v));

// Get numerics only where value > 0.
$array = array_filter($array, fn($v) => is_numeric($v) && ($v > 0));
```

Finally:

```
public static function average(array $array, bool $includeEmpties = true): float
{
    $array = array_filter($array, fn($v) => (
        $includeEmpties ? is_numeric($v) : is_numeric($v) && ($v > 0)
    ));

    return array_sum($array) / count($array);
}
```

Credits: [froq.util.Arrays](https://github.com/froq/froq-util/commit/4d298d9b92366ecf83c6a38ae47f2b1447065318)